# A comprehensive list of PayPals APIs and their intended usage?

Tags: paypal

At my current company I have inherited an undocumented PayPal integration.  As far as I can tell it uses a part of PayPal called the "PayPal checkout".  This is similar but different than the PayPal IPN API.

After scouring the PayPal documentation I am still finding obscure pages talking about new APIs.  Does anybody know of a clear, concise, sane list of PayPal's APIs and their intended usage?

Comment: IPN is not an API. It's an asynchronous PayPal POST which gets posted to your IPN script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check http://www.programmableweb.com/api/paypal